# Как получить сумму всех значений в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Желательно одной строчкой, и с быстрой обработкой, так как записей может быть миллионы.

```js
let items = [
  {qty: "5.45"},
  {qty: "7.15"},
  {qty: "1.85"}
];
let min = Math.min(...items.map(e => e.qty));
let max = Math.max(...items.map(e => e.qty));
let sum = 0; // как получить сумму всех значений ?
console.log(min);
console.log(max);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @hindmost, а как это применить к моему массиву?

Comment: См. "Примеры" там же

Comment: "Желательно с быстрой обработкой": items.map(e => e.qty) сохранить в переменную, и для min, и для max, и для reduce суммы использовать его. А возможно и min-max определить внутри reduce будет быстрее, чем так. Надо измерять)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let items = [
  {qty: "5.45"},
  {qty: "7.15"},
  {qty: "1.85"}
];

console.log(
  items.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + +cur.qty, 0)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Добавил еще `.toFixed(2)` чтобы обрезать лишнее

Answer (score 2):

```js
let items = [
  {qty: "5.45"},
  {qty: "7.15"},
  {qty: "1.85"}
];
let min = Math.min(...items.map(e => e.qty));
let max = Math.max(...items.map(e => e.qty));
let sum = 0;

// Сумма элементов массива 
items.forEach((item)=>sum+=(+item.qty));

console.log(min);
console.log(max);
console.log(sum);
```